# PHP cUrl - unable to call page through non standard port

Tags: php, curl

Let's begin with simple graph:

```
Local www server for testing purposes (application A)
(127.0.0.1:80)
             \->-cUrl call->-\
                              \ 
                             WebService Server (application B)
                             (1.1.1.1:7777)
                              /
             /->-cUrl call->-/
Hosting www server (application A)
(2.2.2.2:80)
```

I have two applications:

1. Application A - calls Application B to load data
2. Application B - process some data and return in REST response

Application A uses cUrl to get data from Application B. Function responsible for this call looks like this (function is used in application A, $url is the address to application B):

```
private function loadData($ids) {

    $url = 'http://1.1.1.1:7777/loadData';
    $data = 'data=' . json_encode($ids);

    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $result = curl_exec($c);
    $decoded = json_decode($result);
    if (!$decoded) {
        Logger::logInfo(sprintf('Unable to decode json [result=%s]', $result));
    }
    if (curl_errno($c)) {
        Logger::logInfo(sprintf('cUrl error: [errno: %s; errmsg: %s]', curl_errno($c), curl_error($c)));
    }

    return $decoded;
}
```

And the problem is...

Curl call through port 7777 works fine from local server but doesn't work from hosting server. If instead of port 7777 I will use standard port 80, it works fine. Where is the problem? Is it some firewall on hosting server?

Conclusion:

```
**Works**: Local www server (application A) ->-cUrl call->- WebService Server (application B) (1.1.1.1:7777)
**Works**: Local www server (application A) ->-cUrl call->- WebService Server (application B) (1.1.1.1:80)
**Works**: Hosting www server (application A) ->-cUrl call->- WebService Server (application B) (1.1.1.1:80)
**Does not work**: Hosting www server (application A) ->-cUrl call->- WebService Server (application B) (1.1.1.1:7777)
```

Comment: Have you checked your server if it has port 7777 open?

Comment: As I wrote I can load data from my local sever so port is opened.

Comment: You need to check if there is a firewall blocking that port, and check if the server is listening on that port.

Comment: @JonathanM, should I check it on hosting server?

Comment: Yes, that is what you should do.

Comment: try doing telnet from app a to app b: telnet 1.1.1.1 7777 if it wont pass meaning port 7777 is closed on server a because you manage to connect from local to servr b